# Bootstrap Accordion: subcollapse should close on close of supercollapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-accordion

```
<div id="accordion">
    <a role="button" data-parent="#accordion" href="#supercollapse1"> ITEM1 </a>
    <div id="supercollapse1">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#subcollapse1" onclick=updateContent()> SUBITEM1 </a>
            <div id="subcollapse1">
                CONTENT
            </div>
    </div>
    <a role="button" data-parent="#accordion" href="#superollapse2"> ITEM2 </a>
    <div id="supercollapse2">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#subcollapse2" onclick=updateContent()> SUBITEM2 </a>
            <div id="subcollapse2">
                CONTENT
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**What happens** When I open supercollapse1 and then subcollapse1 and then supercollapse2, supercollapse1 closes together with subcollapse1 and supercollapse2 opens. Then I open supercollapse1 - supercollapse2 closes and *supercollapse1 together with subcollapse1* opens.

**What I want to achieve** When supercollapse1 and subcollapse1 are open and I open supercollapse2, supercollapse1 closes *together* with subcollapse1, so that subcollapse1 does not show when supercollapse1 is opened again.

**Motive** All subcollapses share one content item which is generated each time they open. So when I already opened subcollapse1, then open subcollapse2 and go back to subcollapse1 - it is already open and content does not get generated.

Tried to be as clear as possible. No offense for the pseudocodish example.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, closing the level1 accordion(s) should close the level2 accordion(s) that are inside of the level1 accordion(s)

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/459nzh32/

The trick is to listen for the [hide event](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#events) of a level1 accordion, then find its children and close them too, here is an example with jquery:

```
$('.level1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).find('.level2').collapse('hide');
});
```